# Mysql charset problem

Tags: mysql, charset

I'm trying to import some data from one server to another. But when I do it, I'm having problems with charset.

Words like Goiânia became GoiÃ¢ni and conceição became conceiÃ§Ã£o

My Application was set to use latin1 charset

Server 1 : 
MySQL Charset : UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
table collation : latin1_swedish_ci

Server 2 :
MySQL Charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
table collation : latin1_swedish_ci

Command I used to export  data from server 1
mysqldump -u root -p --default-character-set=iso-8859-1 database_name > db.sql

Command used to restore to server 2
mysql -u root -p database_name < db.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version of mysql, you want to use either:

--default-character-set=latin1

or

--default-character-set=utf8

There is an odd bug in some versions of mysqldump where specifying utf8 on the command line would double encode a table already encoded as utf8 which was fixed a year or so ago in 5.0.51+ if I recall.

If your character sets are specified correctly in the tables, I don't believe you need to use the default-character-set when doing the dump as it takes it from the table collation and character set.

Answer (score 0):

Doublecheck the collation and charset in `server 1`. It looks like it's a different format and even though you force another one (`iso-8859-1`) on the export this could not work. Double-check it on table and database, etc..

Let me know if this helps.